# PHP - Converting a string written to a variable to a time format

Tags: php

So I am pulling some data from a internal jsp page with `DOMDocument` and using a php script to insert that into a database.  It pulls the data and I have so far got everything the way I want it, but the time that is output on the page, which is in a string format is in the following format:

```
12:05:00a //for am
10:15:00p //for pm, obviously
```

I was thinking I could use `strtotime` (but I'm open to suggestions).  Here is how it is coded:

```
$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
$scheduled_time = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $scheduled_time;
```

I know the answer probably very easy, but I haven't had to work much with converting times.  It can be in military time as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a date element to work with or just time?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a time format.  '12:05:00' is fine for inserting into a `time` field.  You do however have an issue witha that last character, determining `AM` from `a`, and `PM` from `p`.

So, just sort that with a `str_replace()`;

```
$replaceFrom = array('a', 'p');
$replaceTo   = array(' AM',' PM');

$time = str_replace($replaceFrom,$replaceTo,$scheduled_time);
echo date("H:i", strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
echo date("G:i", strtotime($time));
```

or you can try like this also

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime("10:15 PM"));
```

also, you can try to do this

```
$date = new \DateTime();
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2015-09-14 10:15:00

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
#output: 10:15pm
```